# How to select the right Id when clicked?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am displaying users in a list with their photo, name etc... and then I am grabbing the value of the element that has the id "uid" :

```
$scope.toUserView = function() {
  var uid = document.getElementById('userUID').textContent;
  console.log(uid);
  $state.go('tab.userview');

};
```

Problem is that whoever I click on, I always get the reference of the **FIRST** user in the list of the page and I would like to grab **only** the one I click on.

I tried to add `.click()` at the end of my var but it is not a function.

Any idea ?

**EDIT** : Corresponding HTML :

```
<ion-list class="item-border-off list-fav">
        <a  ><ion-item ng-click="toUserView()" ng-repeat="user in users" class="item-remove-animate item-avatar">
            <img ng-src="{{user.photoURL}}">
            <h2>
                {{user.name}}
            </h2>
            <p >{{user.description}}</p>
            <p id="userUID">{{user.uid}}</p>
            <!-- button options -->
            <ion-option-button>
                <i class="icon ion-ios-trash-outline"></i>
            </ion-option-button>
            <ion-option-button>
                <i class="icon ion-ios-chatbubble-outline"></i>
            </ion-option-button>
        </ion-item></a>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML also?

Comment: Hello, I have just added the corresponding HTML !

Comment: You can pass the `user` to the function `ng-click="toUserView(user)"`

Comment: @Titus beat me to it! =) FrenchyNYC check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566648/pass-user-details-in-jade-to-angular-function

Comment: Hey guys, all I want to retrieve is the user.uid and store it in database and your solution sounds the best ! Can you en light me on the code to use for the whole syntax ? I have updated my HTML because there was mistakes !

Comment: Oops, nevermind, a solution fits perfectly what I want to do a little bit lower from another user, I really appreciate it ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corresponding HTML

```
     <a  ><ion-item ng-click="toUserView($index)" ng-repeat="user in users" class="item-remove-animate item-avatar">
                        <img ng-src="{{user.photoURL}}">
                        <h2 id={{user.uid}}>
                            {{user.name}}
                        </h2>
                        <p >{{user.description}}</p>
                        <p id="userUID{{$index}}">{{user.uid}}</p>
                        <!-- button options -->
                        <ion-option-button>
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-trash-outline"></i>
                        </ion-option-button>
                        <ion-option-button>
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-chatbubble-outline"></i>
                        </ion-option-button>
                    </ion-item></a>
```

JS

```
    $scope.toUserView = function(ind) {
      var uid = document.getElementById('userUID'+ind).textContent;
      console.log(uid);
      $state.go('tab.userview');

    };
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! It works like a charm, now I will see if I can store this in the database ! Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

You seem to repeat the `<p id="userUID"></p>` in a loop.

`id` attributes should be unique to a page by definition.

`document.getElementById('test')` returns the first element having the `id` attribute set to `test`.

You should either add something unique to your ids, or use `class="userUID"` instead.